# How to insert a for loop in the middle of an if/else if/else statement?

Tags: javascript

So I have to handle some wrong input in my game, so I wrote this while loop. The first if statement checks if the player asks himself, and the else if checks if a player asks a player that doesn't exist, if none of the above are true then it exits the while loop.

Now, I need to do the second else if with a for loop that takes the variable playerNum as the number of times to run the loop, playerNum is the number of players that are playing. I'm not sure on how to structure this so that it works, because the for loop breaks up the if/else if/else statement so that else doesn't work. Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Is it possible to combine the first if with the else if statement as well?

```
var wrongPlayer = true;
    var player = askPlayer(); //Prompt to get a player to ask

    while (wrongPlayer) { //Run as long as the player input is wrong

        if (player === playerArray[turn].name) { //Player asks himself
            player = askPlayer(); //Prompt again   
        }
        else if (player != playerArray[0].name) { //Need to do this with a loop instead
            player = askPlayer();                 //depending on how many players there are
        }                                         //I have the player count stored in playerNum
        else {
            wrongPlayer = false; //Jump out of the loop
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not do so in an if statement, but have a separate loop (probably `while`) and check in the end of any of the players in the array matched.

Answer (score 0):

You should validate in the `askPlayer` function, then it can just recurse rather than you calling it a bunch of times in a loop. Or you could make a validation function that is mutually recursive with `askPlayer`. Either is better than what you had.

```
var playerArray = []; //populate however
var NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS = playerArray.length;
var i = NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS;

function askPlayer(player) { 
    var askedPlayer = prompt(player + ', which player do you want to ask?'); 
    if (askedPlayer == player ||
        playerArray.indexOf(askedPlayer) == -1) {
        alert('Not a valid player to ask');
        askedPlayer = askPlayer(); //calls self here
    }
    return askedPlayer; 
}

while (i--) {
    var playerAsked = askPlayer(playerArray[i]);
    //do whatever here for the turn logic
}
```

Comment: This made me confused on how to implement in my own code, this is my askPlayer function: <code>function askPlayer() {
    var player = playerArray[turn].name;
    var askedPlayer = prompt(player + ', which player do you want to ask?');
    return askedPlayer;
}</code>